# expl3: Expand every item once when adding to a clist

Tags: expl3

I want to add items to a clist and expand every item once. But the (to my eyes) natural `\clist_set:No` didn't work as expected as it expanded only the first item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\testa{blub}
\def\testb{blabla}
\clist_set:No\mylist{\testa,\testb}
\clist_show:N\mylist
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

 The comma list \mylist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {blub}
>  {\testb }.
```

So what is the correct way to do this? Does one really have to use some loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `o` variant just expands the first token after the brace.

You have to add the items one by one:

```
\clist_new:N \l_ulrike_mylist_clist

\clist_map_inline:nn { \testa , \testb }
 {
  \clist_put_right:No \l_ulrike_mylist_clist { #1 }
 }
```

Of course you can build your syntactic sugar for this.

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \ulrike_clist_set_exp:Nn
 {
  \clist_clear:N #1
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \clist_put_right:No #1 { ##1 }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Still seems odd that `o` wouldn't expand *everything* once. It might be a flaw in how I understand expansion, but only expanding the first token feels wrong. Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: @SeanAllred What's *everything*? By definition, `o` means a braced argument, whose first item is expanded once. Making it act differently depending on the context is not really along the guidelines.

Comment: I guess I wasn't familiar with that particular of the definition: "whose *first* item is expanded once". I'm not saying it should act differently depending on context; I guess I'm saying that the definition doesn't make much sense to me as a layman in TeX expansion :)

Comment: From `texdoc expl3`: "`o`: One-level-expanded token or braced token list." The rest of the paragraph *does* go on to explain that only the first token in a token list will be expanded (like you say). To answer my own side-question, it's a nicer way to use `\expandafter`. The fact that it only expands the first token might not be in perfect alignment with "One-level-expanded token or token list", but it is in perfect alignment with its implied implementation. Just seems strange to me – that's all :)

Comment: @SeanAllred The fact is that one can apply `\cs_generate_variant:Nn <function> { o }` to functions accepting either `N` or `n` arguments. But in the case of `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \funct:N { o }` one should ensure that when `\func:o \token` is called, the first level expansion of `\token` is exactly one token.

Comment: Well like @SeanAllred it didn't feel right for me too. The list command (and also `\clist_put_right`) is in my eyes a "loop" command which does something with every item in turn. So it is odd that the "o" is executed only for the first argument and that one has to surround it with an additional mapping command -- even if from the technical point the "after the braces" is correct.  What in your opinion would be a good (kernel) name for a command which does what I wanted to do?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well what you're going after is a new way to treat an argument, so it would 'naturally' be a new argspec character (`O` came to mind). But I'm *really* not sure on how kosher this is – introducing a new argspec character opens the door to a lot of fragmentation in the language (unless it's added to the kernel).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My idea is that setting a clist that way is wrong to begin with. Can you add a use case?

Comment: @egreg: The use case is a bit complicated but basically I have a bunch of commands filled with `.tl_set:N` keys and I want to get a list with the values, so I need to expand all the commands once.

Comment: @Sean, Ulrike: the argument specifiers describe what happens to the argument *before* the function acts on it. The o-type argument doesn't know that its one-level expanded content will be an argument to be set as a clist. The behaviour is as it should be IMHO, otherwise argument specifiers would mean different things in different functions which I'd find more confusing than helpful...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer A loop seems the best approach, then.